# create 2 instances of h2o in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, multiple-instances, h2o

I have a random forest model using h2o.randomForest().

Now, I need to score a lot of data using h2o.predict(). Due to some constraints I can not score all the data at once. So basically I want to score different data sets in a loop. So, to speed up the process I want to score multiple datasets at the same time by running the same script in 2 different R instances. But when I do it, one instance runs fine but other instances give me the following error. Sometimes both instances give this error.

```
Error in .h2o.__checkConnectionHealth(conn) : 
 H2O connection has been severed. Cannot connect to instance at http://127.0.0.1:54321/
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 54321: Address already in use
```

Above error is not even consistent, sometimes I get it sometimes I don't.

I am initializing the h2o and predicting like following in all R instances.

```
h2oServer = h2o.init(nthreads = -1, max_mem_size = '8g')
h2.predict(model, test_data)
```

How can I achieve this? How do I use the h2o cloud through 2 different R instances?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In genenral, the method that you are trying to utilize does not speed the process up since scoring a single dataset will occupy the CPU's, multiple calls will only create unnecessary contention.

Also, you can only boot a single H2O instance from within R, if you are trying to boot more than one instance, you can do so from the command line (java -jar h2o.jar).